# Search for CreditCard numbers in Win Exchange Server

Tags: exchange

Assuming one would like to re-/move or mark all the Emails that contain a credit-card number. How could that be archived on a Windows Exchange Server?

Comment: A specific credit card number? That *might* be doable. But if you're looking for  "random" [credit card numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number) in unstructured message formats? With credit card numbers already differing in length between 14-19 digits depending on the card company and people frequently writing them in subgroups with spaces/dots rather than in a single string? Probably impossible to do with any form of reliability. - The common jargon for such searches (across all mailboxes) is *"eDiscovery"*.

Comment: I'd take all the emails, pass them through a pipe (character after character) and let a piece of code decide if it contains a credit card. If so, mark that email and let the user (who owns the mail) do the last check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Scanning of the mailboxes

In Exchange Server 2007/2010 I would have suggested using [`Export-Mailbox` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998579.aspx) to find/move/delete messages. However, its `-ContentKeywords` & `-SubjectKeywords` does not support regular expressions.

On the other hand, Exchange Server 2013/2016 [In-Place eDiscovery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298021(v=exchg.150).aspx) search query keywords does not support regular expressions either.

If you need to scan all stored messages, suitable third party tools can be found  that supports pattern scanning. Because of the nature of this community I would not recommend any single product.

### Mail flow rules / Transport rules

The exact point when the sensitive information may be leaked is when it goes through the server. Therefore more efficient approach could be handling the problem with mail flow rules as then you won't need to scan whole database on regular basis. And: [transport rules support regular expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997187(v=exchg.141).aspx).

On the article there was an example with social security numbers:

```
New-TransportRule -Name "Social Security Number Block Rule"     `
   -SubjectOrBodyMatchesPatterns '\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d'         `
   -RejectMessageEnhancedStatusCode "5.7.1"                     `
   -RejectMessageReasonText "Rejected: content restrictions"
```

I think this pattern would do the same with Visa and Master Card numbers:

```
   -SubjectOrBodyMatchesPatterns "\d\d\d(\s|.|-)\d\d(\s|.|-)\d\d\d\d"
```

And this with American Express:

```
   -SubjectOrBodyMatchesPatterns "\d\d\d\d(\s|.|-)\d\d\d\d\d\d(\s|.|-)\d\d\d\d\d"
```

Comment: I think you forgot to edit the second line... I believe it should be "\d\d\d\d(\s|.|-)*\d\d\d\d(\s|.|-)*\d\d\d\d(\s|.|-)*\d\d\d\d"   That would match standard Visa/MC format of 4 sets of 4 numbers, with either a space, period, dash, or nothing in between them.